# Can I edit my.ini or my.cnf file in browser?

Tags: mysql, ssh, cpanel, my.cnf

I'm working on whmcs and it requires disabling MYSQL strict mode.

I searched about it and it says you can find it in my.ini or my.cnf.

My problem is that I can't find it in any place in file manager. Can Someone help me find and edit it?

Comment: Is it for internet usage or just local? Cause my work is on internet space

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/general-server-setup/edit-mysql-my-cnf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find and disable MySQL strict mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964325/how-to-find-and-disable-mysql-strict-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not find my.cnf file in your File Manager. Generally it resides in /etc directory.  If you are on shared server, you will not have access of this file.

If you have VPS/Dedi. Server, you can SSH into the server and edit this file. Use any editor like vi, nano to edit this file.

You will have to set blank in   sql-mode i.e.

```
sql_mode=""
```

Then restart MySQL service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on Shared hosting. You are not allowed to do this (edit my.cnf etc) in shared hosting.
If you are using VPS/Dedicated Server, then you can edit /etc/my.cnf via SSH Client and a editor like vi. To edit this file on browser, install "config server explorer" cpanel plugin via SSH on your server. http://configserver.com/cp/cse.html then you can edit system files via WHM.